# Can I use "at the end" the same way as "at last"?

Tags: word-choice

> He has been waiting for this letter for days, and **at last** it has come.

Can I use "at the end" instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct idiomatic expression is:

***[In the end](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+end)***:

> - Eventually; ultimately: All will turn out well in the end.

(AHD)

Compare:

***[In the end](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/in-the-end-at-the-end)***:

> - **In the end is used mostly as an idiom that means "finally," "after a long time," or, "when everything is considered.***" It is often followed by a comma.

Here are some sentences with this idiom:

> - *We worked hard, and in the end, we achieved our goal.
>     In the end, what really matters in a friendship is trust.*

***At the end***:

> - ***At the end is used in the idiom "at the end of the day." which means something similar to in the end (= when everything is considered)***
> - ***However, at the end is most commonly used more literally, as a prepositional phrase followed by of***, to refer to the end of a specific noun. This noun can be a physical object, a period of time, an event, a place, or something more abstract, such as one's patience.

Here are some sentences with at the end + of:

> - *At the end of his life, he had no regrets.
>     Put a period at the end of every sentence.
>     I pay the phone bill at the end of each month.
>     There is a brick building at the end of the driveway.*

(M-W)

Answer (score 3):

The expression *in the end* could be used, but I feel that the adverb, *finally*, sounds more natural to my ears.

> He has been waiting for this letter for days, and **finally** it's come.

Contracting "it has" to "it's" improves the flow still.

> **[finally](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/finally)**
>   after a long time, typically when there has been difficulty or delay.
>   "he finally arrived to join us"
>
> *synonyms*: eventually, ultimately, **in the end**, by and by, at length, after a long time, after some time; at long last, in the long run, when all was said and done, in the fullness of time; *informal*: **at the end of the day**

Oxford Dictionaries